# The time period Rama and Sita lives in Ayodhya after returning from Vanavasa and other Ramayana details

Tags: ramayana, rama, sita, valmiki

[This](https://twitter.com/AnaMyID/status/928465961358835713?s=20&t=lJU7wY97IAqeVRh5lNsqaw) sick post in Twitter makes me angry. It says Rama and Seetha lived in Ayodhya for 12 years and then was in Vanvas for 13 years together, so it is 25 years and Seetha never conceived, but soon after returning back to Ayodhya she conceived. Implying bad things, these are the same kind of people during Ramayana who spoke badly and spread bad rumours. They were there in Treta Yuga, they have become worst in rumour spreading in Kali Yuga.

[image]

Any way we Hindus need to answer these kinds of uneducated idiots with bad motive.

This question can be split into three parts. Before Vanvas, Vanvas, After Vanvas.

A. When Rama and Seetha left for Vanvas, Seetha was only just 18, so she was basically a minor. This solves the first part of the question

B. And if I remember correctly while leaving Sri Rama takes a vow of celibacy and says will not take alcohol etc in Vanvas. Can any one give the source in Ramayana?

C. Now can anyone give source or any calculation in Ramyana between the period of Rama's return from Vanvas and the eventual exile of Seetha.